# Is there any way to reset the value of an attribute every day in dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

So, I have a table called "Users" and these users have an attribute called "DailyResult". Every day at 00:00 I want to reset the value of this attribute to 0. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Any specific reason why the DailyResult cannot be a seperate DynamoDB table?

Comment: No, only [TTL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html) is supported natively.

Comment: I don't have a big reason why the attribute is in the same table. So I suppose it is better to create a separate table and use TTL, right?

Comment: Rather than restructure your database, why not a very simple Lambda, run by CloudWatch at whatever time you want?

Comment: So, the best choice is to create a cron job on aws lambda and it will scan all the table and update the attribute of all items?

Comment: Well, "best" is a matter of opinion.  The Lambda would be pretty simple and you can run a Cloudwatch Event Rule when it makes sense.   You'll need a cron schedule in there but realize that all times in Cloudwatch are UTC and you have to decide where on the planet you want midnight to be.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.html has update code for a variety of languages.

Comment: DynamoDB TTL isn't appropriate for your use case. It expires items "shortly after the date and time of the specified timestamp" (and what "shortly" means is not defined afaik) plus it deletes the item (it won't reset a value to zero). I would use the option suggested by @stdunbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that all the answers helped me to reach a result, but I ended up implementing the @stdunbar idea, in my user case it worked perfectly. I created a lambda that runs every day at midnight and updates the attribute DailyResult to zero

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in way to do exactly what you asked for, but there is an easy way to simulate it:

1. Every time you set the DailyResult attribute on an item, also set the DailyResult_Today attribute to the current day number (a number increasing by 1 every midnight).
2. When you read read the item, if DailyResult_Today is *not* today's day number, treat the DailyResult as being zero.
3. If you have update expressions or condition expressions or filter expressions using DailyResult, you always need to add to the expression logic which will take it as 0 if the DailyResult_Today isn't today's day number.

Alternatively, other people suggested you should use the TTL feature. But that method comes short in two things: First, when the time comes it will delete your entire item, not just the attribute. Second, you have no guarantee when exactly the item gets deleted. If you really want to use the TTL features, you can use additional tricks to make it work:

1. Don't put this attribute in the same items as usual, but in separate items (inside the same table, no need for a separate table). Add the day number (wrapping around at midnight) to the item key. For example, if you have an item with key "xyz", in day 7 add its DailyResult to item "xyz_7".
2. On these special items, put a TTL to ensure they'll be deleted in roughly a day.
3. When you want to read DailyResult from item xyz, read it from xyz_7 instead - where "7" is the current day number right now. At one second past midnight, this will start reading a yet-nonexistent item, and you should treat a missing result as zero.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the daily reset counter using dynamodb's conditional expression.

benefits:

- works on per user basis.
- no cron jobs.

This also helps me track the total no. of OTPs requested and mark notorious users.

```
const params = {
        TableName,
        Key: { UserId },
        UpdateExpression: "set #count.#onDate = if_not_exists(#count.#onDate, :start) + :inc",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':inc': 1,
            ':start': 0,
            ':MAX': maxOTPs
        },
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            '#count': 'count',
            '#onDate': new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]
        },
        ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW",
        ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(#count.#onDate) or (#count.#onDate < :MAX)',
    };
```

I know it's a different way (using JSON objects, but it sure works),
the attachment shows how [DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l52nv.png) looks like.

[db item image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l52nv.png)
[dynamodb query image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C97SC.png)